# What's the difference between Proxy-Authenticate and WWW-Authenticate?

Tags: http, http-authentication

I've read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication and the Basic Authentication chapter from *HTTP: The Definitive Guide*.

I thought `Proxy-Authenticate + Proxy-Authorization + status code 407` was essentially the same as `WWW-Authenticate + Authorization + status code 401`. I thought if the server responded `WWW-Authenticate + 401` or `Proxy-Authorization + 407`, under both conditions, the browser would pop up an auth dialog, and then the browser would send the credentials with the `Authorization` or `Proxy-Authorization` header.

The "WWW-Authenticate combination headers" did work as expected, while the "Proxy combination headers" did not. For `Proxy-Authorization + 407`, I get `ERR_UNEXPECTED_PROXY_AUTH` in Chrome and get nothing happened in Firefox(**No auth dialog popping up!**).

Error in Chrome:

```
This site can’t be reached.
The webpage at http://localhost:5000/http_auth might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_UNEXPECTED_PROXY_AUTH
```

So what's the difference between these 2 sets of similar headers? When and where do I use `Proxy-Authenticate`? Practical exmaples that I can run would be much appreciated.

---

I am using Python with Flask for testing.

My serverside code:

WWW-Authenticate

```python
@app.route('/www_auth')
def ha():
    print("====request headers begin======")
    print(request.headers)
    print("====request headers end======")
    if 'Authorization' in request.headers and request.headers['Authorization'] == 'Basic MTIzOjQ1Ng==':
        return render_template('demo.html')
    else:
        resp = make_response(render_template('demo.html'), 401)
        resp.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Basic realm="WWW-Authenticate required :)"'
        return resp
```

Proxy-Authenticate

```python
@app.route('/proxy_auth')
def haha():
    print("====request headers begin======")
    print(request.headers)
    print("====request headers end======")
    if 'Proxy-Authorization' in request.headers and request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] == 'Basic MTIzOjQ1Ng==':
        return render_template('demo.html')
    else:
        resp = make_response(render_template('demo.html'), 407)
        resp.headers['Proxy-Authenticate'] = 'Basic realm="Proxy-Authenticate required :)"'
        return resp
```

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: @n.m. No. I turned off all extensions in Chrome and got error too.

Comment: Proxy authentication only works for for proxy server, whose protocol has small changes compared to http

Comment: A proxy is a message-forwarding agent selected by a client (RFC7230). If you don't have any selected, then you don't have any to authenticate against.

Comment: To authenticate with a proxy, you need a proxy. Seems obvious.

Comment: @n.m. Ok let me try again. I am going to manually configure a proxy(`http://localhost:5000/http_auth`) in Firefox and then visit a random site see if there will be auth dialog popping up.

Comment: http://localhost:5000/http_auth is not a valid proxy. A proxy is a server that runs on some host/port combo. There is no path.

Comment: @n.m. Yes you are right. I just noticed that when I was trying to set the host. I changed the path to `/` and now it seems to work... I am checking that now :)

Comment: I recommend to take a short break from coding and read some RFCs. They are fascinating.

Comment: @n.m. Check my experiment results :) . If it had not been your hint, I wouldn't have known how to test.

Comment: @Ferrybig Can you explain a little bit? I've observed some practical behaviours with some tests(see my answer), but any other in-depth opinions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests and here's what I found. (I took a look at RFC and as usual it's too overwhelming :) )

The `Proxy-Authenticate` set of headers can indeed result in auth pop-up dialog too. But it is something that one must manually set in the client/browser at first. Specifically, for example in Firefox, it's related to the **proxy setting**.

[image]

The `Proxy-Authenticate` set of headers is used when you connects to a proxy which needs username and password.

**Attention**: You need to set the root path to your proxy function like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def haha():
    #rest of the code
```

The workflow is:

```
                -----------------------------------Step 1---------------------------------------------------->        
client/browser  <---Step 2, 407,Proxy-Authorization response header, required username and password----------- proxy               
                ----Step 3, Proxy-Authorization request headers, contains credentials------------------------>      --------> target website
                ----Subsequent requests, Proxy-Authorization request headers with credentials is still sent-->      ---------> target website
```

In this case, the `Proxy-Authorization`(with credentials) will be sent automatically for each request.

If the server does not require authentication, then the client can visit the target website directly, and there's no `Proxy-Authorization` header in the request. (Most free http proxies that you find on the Web works in this way I think)

---

I also tried the `WWW-Authenticate` set of headers while I had set the **proxy setting** in Firefox. The result is that: Every time I visit a new website, I need to authenticate again. So obviously the `WWW-Authenticate` set of headers aren't meant to be used in this case.

---

Any other in-depth opinions/explanation would be appreciated. After all I merely did some tests and I want to know more.

Comment: Btw, the proxy server is just an ordinary server, you can do whatever you want after authenticating. You can make it a real proxy server or for example in my tests, I make it return a same html page every time.